# Hide Guest Users Email Addresses from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, microsoft

Does anyone know a way to hide email addresses on SharePoint - in particular when working or accessing a shared file - or to otherwise replace the email with a name?

Further details:
Our volunteers are registered as external guest users on SharePoint in order to access the same files and folders, and will at times work on the same Word document. At the moment when they're on the same file, it shows their email address - which tend to be personal email addresses. I'd like to hide their email addresses from being visible to each other, or to replace it with a name rather than an email address e.g. Volunteer 62, so we could still keep a track of who has accessed a file, while retaining their privacy. Otherwise just to remove it from being viewed at all.

It's been suggested that:

- We just set volunteers up with their own volunteer email address, but then this means we have to accept privacy policies on their behalf when creating them, while it can open a can of worms in them using the email in a way not linked to the organisation.
- Don't use SharePoint - however this allows us to manage email access to external users, to provide Word to everyone regardless of whether they have their own personal copy, and options such as reviewing, and editing restrictions.

I'm not sure if there is a guidable solution with Microsoft's current setup, and their tech support are unsure themselves, so otherwise is it possible to hire a programmer/developer/coder to find a solution, or with its permission settings - is this impossible to do?

Thanks

I've added some screenshots to help, but for protecting the volunteers I've blanked out the first part of the email.

**Guest users email addresses show in the following places**

When logged into the same article:

[image]

Also in catch-up:
[image]

And in changes made:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Register another custom domain on your tenant purely for volunteers to use e.g. a domain that is not seen as a domain linked to your organisation, like the domain you use for interaction with the public.

Then use this domain to give users accounts.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm not quite understanding what you mean?

Comment: You said you were concerned about a username being given to a user being used elsewhere but you could give them a username with a domain that isn't obviously linked to your organisation by registering another custom domain on your Microsoft 365 tenant. Additionally, you don't have to give them an Exchange (email inbox) with the account you have given them. Most websites force a user to validate their email address but they can't do that if the account you have given them doesn't have an inbox.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Sadly they would need the inbox in order to have access to SharePoint, as an email is sent providing a link and code, and we would still have the problem with privacy policies - as they should be looking at the privacy agreement and deciding their choices with any email designated to them, while if we set this up, the choice is removed. Thank you though.

Comment: You can set the email address in AD to their personal email address while their UPN (username) uses the custom domain. This way you don't need to give them an Exchange licence/inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it is by default that when external users access the same file at the same time, they could only see others' names instead of address:

[image]

Is there some misunderstanding in this issue? If so, please provide some screenshot to let me have a check, thanks.

Comment: It would be great if I could have a name showing instead of the email address - I've attached screenshots. But when I asked Microsoft tech support they said there was no way to do this and it would be the email address as this is how external users are given access. May I ask how you have managed to show the name instead? Because if I could do this I could assign a unique, but anonymous name to protect their data.